# 0 of 1 issue in Xcode

Tags: xcode, debugging

I have following problem:

[image]

Navigator shows me 0 of 1 issue. Weird. Anyone knows how to fix it?

I tried to solve that problem by:

- remove current branch and then checkout them again from origin
- cleaning Xcode (CMD + SHIFT + K)
- restarting Xcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

Clean with **CMD + ALT + SHIFT + K** - This will delete all of the products and intermediate files in the build folder.

Answer (score 0):

Restart Xcode-->Clean-->Run

This will fix.